# Embeding image in Flex 4 spark button control

Tags: flex4, mxmlc

How can I embed an image in [Flex 4 button control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d9f.html)? [I found one here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Applying_custom_images_to_Buttons-282.html), but its for flex 3 mx controls. I just want an image above a text label on the button for accessibility reasons. Can someone suggest any technique [both using skins](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html) and not using them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Flex 4.5 SDK latest build http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero  - Spark Button now has "icon" property